# How do I query tags from the TFS database?

Tags: tfs

I am writing some custom SSRS reports for our QA teams and I need to add test case "Tags" to my query.  It is my understanding these are not in the TFS_Warehouse.  I have found dbo.tbl_TagDefinition in the operational store but cannot figure out how to join it to a work item.

Comment: Which edition of TFS and VS are you using?

Comment: You should **not** query the operational store directly.

Comment: I am so troubled by the amount of people saying how you should not query the operational store directly. We are talking about a production level MS SQL Server instance here, not a quick DB thrown together out of paper mache. Are we not programmers and technologists? If we find a way to do something, we do it. What's the risk of querying the store directly? 1. Slight performance impact (to a production DB that can handle it) 2. The DB could change between releases. Fine. We can deal with that. When it changes (which it didn't between 2015 and 2017) we will engineer another solution then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a tag to work item query directly if your TFS contains the updates added with TFS 2013 Update 2 or later.

If you want to query from database, check [this case](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6aefbb75-e63d-4090-a365-18a3d160c372/how-to-query-tfs-2012-database-for-work-items-by-tag?forum=tfsreporting):

TFS 2013 and up:

```
SELECT DISTINCT workItem.ID, tbl_TagDefinition.Name
    --,tbl_PropertyValue.ArtifactId, *
FROM tbl_TagDefinition
    LEFT JOIN tbl_PropertyDefinition ON tbl_PropertyDefinition.Name = 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Tagging.TagDefinition.' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(400), tbl_TagDefinition.TagId)
    LEFT JOIN tbl_PropertyValue ON tbl_PropertyValue.PropertyId = tbl_PropertyDefinition.PropertyId
    --LEFT JOIN WorkItemLongTexts ON WorkItemLongTexts.ID = tbl_PropertyValue.ArtifactId
    left join tbl_WorkItemCoreLatest workItem on WorkItemsAre.ID = tbl_PropertyValue.ArtifactId
WHERE 
    (
       SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN IntValue = 0 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) NB 
       FROM tbl_PropertyValue PROP_CNT 
       WHERE PROP_CNT.PropertyId = tbl_PropertyDefinition.PropertyId 
          AND workItem.ID = PROP_CNT.ArtifactId
    ) > 0
```

Prior to TFS 2013:

```
SELECT DISTINCT WorkItemsAre.ID, WorkItemsAre.Title, tbl_TagDefinition.Name
    --,tbl_PropertyValue.ArtifactId, *
FROM tbl_TagDefinition
    LEFT JOIN tbl_PropertyDefinition ON tbl_PropertyDefinition.Name = 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Tagging.TagDefinition.' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(400), tbl_TagDefinition.TagId)
    LEFT JOIN tbl_PropertyValue ON tbl_PropertyValue.PropertyId = tbl_PropertyDefinition.PropertyId
    --LEFT JOIN WorkItemLongTexts ON WorkItemLongTexts.ID = tbl_PropertyValue.ArtifactId
    left join WorkItemsAre on WorkItemsAre.ID = tbl_PropertyValue.ArtifactId
WHERE 
    (
       SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN IntValue = 0 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) NB 
       FROM tbl_PropertyValue PROP_CNT 
       WHERE PROP_CNT.PropertyId = tbl_PropertyDefinition.PropertyId 
          AND WorkItemsAre.ID = PROP_CNT.ArtifactId
    ) > 0
```

Comment: Is this an official Microsoft recommendation? I've always been told that writing queries against the operational store is **unsupported** and should not be done.

Comment: The official recommendation is to never query the operational store.  In reality there are some cases where the API or Warehouse Adapters are not very attractive.  We came across this same dilemma with querying Test Case Steps and I saw quite a few unofficial recommendations to just query the operational store and be prepared for possible breakage on upgrade.

Comment: Thanks @Cece!  I went to implement this and discovered we just upgraded to TFS2015 last week and now dbo.workitemsare is gone.  [I posted a new question under TFS2015](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36778832/reporting-tfs-2015-tag-data-in-custom-ssrs-reports)

Comment: Replace `dbo.workitemsare` for TFS2013 with `dbo.tbl_WorkItemCoreLatest` in TFS2015, and remove the Title column from this query (this comes as a relation from the `dbo.WorkItemCustomLatest`). I'll show how to add the title if anyone responds and is curious.

Answer (score 3):

This is based off of @Robby's answer and still seems to work as of Azure DevOps 2019:

```
   select distinct 
       wcl.id, 
       td.Name from tbl_WorkItemCoreLatest wcl
left outer join tbl_PropertyValue pv on wcl.id = pv.artifactid
left outer join tbl_PropertyDefinition pd on pv.PropertyId = pd.PropertyId
left outer join tbl_TagDefinition td on pd.Name = ltrim(rtrim('Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Tagging.TagDefinition.' + cast(td.TagId as varchar(1000))))
where td.Name is not null
```

Answer (score 2):

The TFS 2015 db is convoluted, but here's how you query for a tag to find all it's matching work Items

```
select * from tbl_WorkItemCoreLatest
where
    id in
    (
        select CONVERT(INT, artifactid) from tbl_PropertyValue
        where
        PropertyId in
            (
                select PropertyId from tbl_PropertyDefinition 
                where 
                name in
                    (
                        select ltrim(rtrim('Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Tagging.TagDefinition.' + cast(tagid as varchar(1000)))) 
                            from tbl_TagDefinition 
                                where name like '%<TAG NAME TO SEARCH FOR>%'  -- Tag name you're looking for
                    )
            )
    )
```

Hope this helps :-)

## TFS #TFS2015

-R