# Reporting TFS 2015 tag data in custom SSRS Reports

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I need to add tag reporting capability to a collection of custom SSRS reports which query TFS_Warehouse (and in one case I had to query the operational store to gather test case steps).  These reports all use a SQL Server datasource connected to my custom TFS_Warehouse_Extensions database.

If this sounds familiar, I asked this question yesterday and got a wonderful response... then I discovered we upgraded from 2013 to 2015 last week and dbo.workitemsare is gone.

I am using VS 2015 and am more of a database developer than a C# programmer (I know just enough to be dangerous).  Is there any way I can get tags from TFS 2015 workitems into my SSRS reports?

Edit: the proposed duplicate answer is not exactly the same problem. Whether or not some work items views went missing is ancillary. My requirement is for a way to query TFS tags in SSRS. So far I consider this unanswered in either thread since no one has proposed a solution that meets the requirement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Table WorkItemsLatest (TFS 2010) missing in TFS 2015 (Collection Database)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36791335/table-workitemslatest-tfs-2010-missing-in-tfs-2015-collection-database)

Answer (score 4):

@Cyndi, I'm a Program Manager with the reporting team. Currently reporting with Tags is not supported aside from queries with the query editor. We do have a new reporting solution we're working on and reporting on tags will be supported. I don't have an exact date for the release yet, but see this [blog post](http://i1.blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2016/01/11/announcing-reporting-capabilities-for-visual-studio-team-services.aspx) for some details. We'll have more announcements to make this summer.

Comment: Good to know it is on the roadmap. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One totally diffrent way would be to use Excel for reporting.

You build a query in TFS and then connect Excel to TFS and use the query. The functionality is kind of limited, but you can use Excels features to make great reports.

One problem with Excel is that you can't (you shouldn't) add further fields to the table you got from TFS. When you update the data, Excel will lock up and nothing happens. 
If you need to use custom fields for your reporting, you should create a second table, where all the data is copied to. This can be as well automated with VBA.

That data can be analysed directly in the table or with a Pivot Table or visualised a Pivot Chart.
With the use of the Pivot feature Excel is able to create powerful reports.

Answer (score -1):

It's not a good idea to query the operational store. This may cause some problems for normal usage.

> You should NEVER write reports directly against the WorkItem* tables
>   in the collection database, since this is an operational store and is
>   100% unsupported and can cause performance problems for normal usage.
>
> Source: [How to query Work Items using SQL on the Relational Warehouse](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/granth/2010/05/09/tfs2010-how-to-query-work-items-using-sql-on-the-relational-warehouse/)

Comment: Have you considered making tags reportable in the work item template? Perhaps just setting reportable to dimension on the Tags field would be good enough. That should get it into the warehouse and the analysis cube.

Comment: They cannot be set to reportable.

Comment: Hi [Patrick-MSFT](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5391065/patrick-msft).  Thanks for the comment.  Do you think there is a way to get tags from TFS 2015 workitems into my SSRS reports from a relational db datasource?  I understand that it is not a good idea to query the operational store so I am hoping for another option.

Comment: @Cyndi1976 I have found something new from  the Microsoft Team Foundation Server global support team. See my update answer. A blog says that Creating reports against the relational database is now officially supported in Team Foundation Server.(2016/01) For more details, please refer the msdn article below: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee939347(VS.100).aspx#RelationalDB Hope the link be helpful. However, I'm not so familar with this field. If you still can't work it out, you may need to ask for help from the global support team.

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT as far as I can tell this still only applies to the `TFS_WAREHOUSE` relational database and not the operational stores. The example views in the image next to the link seem to indicate this as well.