# Table WorkItemsLatest (TFS 2010) missing in TFS 2015 (Collection Database)

Tags: reporting-services, tfs-2015

We recently migrated from TFS 2010 to TFS 2015 and came across that some of the reporting services are not working anymore.

One of the view we created was pulling various information (WorkItem State, Title,Fld10118) from "WorkItemsLatest" table, however, checking the collection database of TFS 2015 indicates that there is no more "WorkItemsLatest" table in TFS 2015 collection database.

I would appreciate if you can advise how to get above mentioned fields in TFS 2015 collection database. I understand that the operational databases are not supported by Microsoft and encourages to retrieve data from Warehouse database, however, we would like to retrieve this data and will allocate some development time in the future to ensure that data is retrieved from the Warehouse database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### WARNING

Even though you've already mentioned this yourself, querying the database tables directly can lead to breaking functionality between updates. With the recent amount of churn in the work item space (new template customization features landing on VSTS and probably coming to TFS vNext and the new workitem form), expect these items to keep changing in the near future.

### Ok, I get it

So, you're probably looking for the following two views:

- `[Tfs_DefaultCollection].[dbo].[vw_denorm_WorkItemCoreLatest]`
- `[Tfs_DefaultCollection].[dbo].[vw_denorm_WorkItemCustomLatest]`

And join them with `tbl_Field` to be able to identify which Custom Field ID matches which Field Name.

Comment: Thanks. One of the thing that drives me crazy is that how to get the "Relationship Diagram" of Collection Database as this will help me to understand the relationships visually. At the moment I am just looking at tables and trying to make some sense, which is quite time consuming and almost make me to pull my hairs (though I am bald ;) Please advise.

Comment: I checked those advised views, however, it does not give us "Title, Fld10118". I would appreciate if you check the query from the following location as I have managed to retrieve everything from TFS 2015 collection database but only three fields (mentioned in question) where I can't get the data. Thanks

http://pastebin.com/sbTFjJGw

Comment: "Relationship Diagram" 
What I meant was that can we can get the "Database Diagram" of Collection database of TFS 2015 so I can visually see the relationships (Primary key, Forign Keys etc), which will help us to understand relationships better.

Comment: No, I am trying to get the contents/data of the field. As this is something I am doing first time; whole purpose of this exercise is to make sure that views/query we are using to produce SSRS reports in TFS 2010 also work in TFS 2015.

Comment: Thanks for your help and patience. I used the following query, howerver, what is the filed name that will give me the value? Sorry for being trouble as not sure how to get data :( 

SELECT TOP 100 vw.* FROM vw_denorm_WorkItemCustomLatest vw
INNER JOIN tbl_Field f ON vw.FieldId = f.FieldId

Comment: Got it. Used the following query to get data. Many thanks for your help and patience. Much appreciated!!

SELECT TOP 100 vw.* FROM vw_denorm_WorkItemCustomLatest vw
INNER JOIN tbl_Field f ON vw.FieldId = f.FieldId AND vw.PartitionId = f.PartitionId
WHERE vw.ID  = 10556 and f.Name ='Title'

Comment: Something not relevant with this; just wondering is there anyway to chat directly with someone (i.e. yourself) here on Stackoverflow or it can only be done through the comments section. Please advise.

Comment: just fyi - I think this also applies to upgrades from TFS 2013 to TFS "15".