# TFS2015 - List how many times tags were used in TFS 2015 On-Premise work items

Tags: sql, sql-server, tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-workitem

​Hello,

​I am trying to write an SQL query to list all tags along with the number of how many times they were used in Work Items in TFS2015.
I cannot find the connection between tbl_WorkItemCoreLatest, tbl_PropertyDefinition and tbl_TagDefinition that would point me to tags used on work items.
I tried to go with the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36757116/how-do-i-query-tags-from-the-tfs-database), but with no success. The query results seems not to match what I see directly in VSTS (eg. searching for a particular tag returns me work items from which some don't have that particular tag, almost as if TFS would store previous states of work items...?)
If there's a way to do that with REST API, that will work as well.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use TFS REST API below to get all work items with `System.Tags` field, then calculate how many times they were used：

```
`http://tfs2015:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/teamproject/_apis/wit/reporting/workitemrevisions?fields=System.Tags&includeLatestOnly=true&api-version=2`
```

Another simple way is creating a work item query with Tags column and open this query in Excel to filter the Tags column.

[image]